# Adding Menu to my post-nav?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm looking to add a menu Home, Contact Us, etc. to this field `<div class="post-nav">` on http://boasish.com. [image]

I'm using Wordpress. The area in black is where I would like the custom menu. My template does not offer me an option to add a widget there so I am looking to add one myself. Everything else on the page is fine where it is I would just like to add a custom menu where I specified

Here is the code in question.

```
<footer class="site-footer" role="contentinfo" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPFooter">
 <div class="wrap">
    <div class="post-nav">
    </div>
 </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: You could just add it to footer.php

Comment: read up on how to modify your templates, lots of documentation and tutorials to go by

Comment: Brian, I tried that and it didn't look good. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Do you want to register a nav menu for those two links, manageable from the admin or would you be happy adding to footer.php if it looks good. Both options end the same, outputting as HTML in your footer.php

Comment: There's really nothing to translate. PHP is a Hypertext Pre processor, and HTML is hypertext markup language. Basically PHP will do what it needs to do before it spills it out to the document. So if you add this html to the end of your footer.php file it can't be inside `<?php ?>` there is no need to echo. If you want something dynamic change it to be dynamic after.

Comment: I wasn't very clear, I've updated my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register your [custom menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus) by adding this to your `functions.php` located within your template directory

```
function my_footer_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('footer-menu',__( 'Footer Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_footer_menu' );
```

And this to your `footer.php` file

```
<footer class="site-footer" role="contentinfo" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPFooter">
  <nav class="nav-primary">
       <div class="wrap">
          <div class="post-nav">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer-menu', 'container_class' => 'menu' ) ); ?>
          </div>
       </div>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Within `wp-admin`, add your menu items from the [menu manager](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel).

I am using `.nav-primary` because its the themes header menu class and so your footer is styled similar

Comment: I'm using a child theme with a parent genesis theme. Should I be editing functions.php and footer.php from the genesis theme or child theme?

Comment: Yeah, duplicate your footer.php file and place it within the child theme and it will take over.